# Markov chain that is $\phi$-irreducible but not $\phi$-recurrent

Tags: probability, markov-chains

In trying to understand the underlying mathematics of the Metropolis-Hasting algorithm, I came across this [paper](https://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/sdtr/ucb/text/501.pdf) on continuous state Markov chains. On page 3, Example 2 gives a Markov chain which is claimed to be strongly $\phi$-irreducible but not $\phi$-recurrent (in the example $\pi$ is used instead of $\phi$)

For convenience I'm transcribing the relevant definitions and the example.

On page 1 the following definitions are given ($P$ is a probability kernel, and $(X, B)$ is a measurable space):

> 1. $P$ is "$\phi$-irreducible" iff for all $x \in X$ and all $A \in B$ with $\phi(A) > 0$, there is a positive integer $n = n_{xA}$ such that $P^n(x, A) > 0$
> 2. $P$ is "strongly $\phi$-irreducible" iff for all $x \in X$ and all $A \in B$ with $\phi(A) > 0$, there is a positive integer $n = n_{xA}$ such that $P^m(x, A) > 0$ for all $m \geq n$
> 3. $P$ is "$\phi$-recurrent" iff for all $x \in X$ and all $A \in B$ with $\phi(A) > 0$, a Markov chain which starts from $x$ at time $0$ hits $A$ at some positive time, a.s.; of course, this time is random

The example is the following:

> Let $X_1$ be a finite set, and $P$ a stochastic matrix on $X_1$, with all entries strictly positive. Under the circumstances, there is a unique stationary probability $\pi$, and $P$ is $\pi$-recurrent. Adjoin a sequence of states 1, 2,..., each with $\pi$-probability $0$, and the following transition rules: $i \rightarrow  i + 1$ with probability $1/2^i$; with the remaining probability, $i$ goes to a point in $X_1$, chosen at random from $\pi$. The resulting kernel is strongly $\pi$-irreducible, but not $\pi$-recurrent, due to the adjoined states.

I don't see why the resulting kernel is not $\pi$-recurrent. Specifically, I take it that the definition of $\phi-recurrent$ is equivalent to: $P(\tau_A = \infty \: | \: starting \: at \: x) = 0$ for all $x \in X$ and all $A \in B$ with $\phi(A) > 0$, where $\tau_A = min\{n > 0, X_n \in A\}$ (in this case $P$ denotes probability, not the kernel)

The states we need to examine for this property are the adjoined states. Hence, if at time $0$ the chain begins at $i$ we have:

$$
P(\tau_A = \infty \: | \: starting \: at \: i) = P(i \rightarrow i + 1)P(\tau_A = \infty \: | \: starting \: at \: i+1) + (1-P(i \rightarrow i + 1))P(\tau_A = \infty \: | \: starting \: at \: x \in X_1)
$$

However, $P(\tau_A = \infty \: | \: starting \: at \: x \in X_1) = 0$, since the initial kernel is $\pi$-recurrent, so:

$$
P(\tau_A = \infty \: | \: starting \: at \: i) = P(i \rightarrow i + 1)P(\tau_A = \infty \: | \: starting \: at \: i+1)
$$

Inductively:

$$
P(\tau_A = \infty \: | \: starting \: at \: i) = \prod_{j=i}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j} = 0
$$

So why isn't the resulting kernel $\pi$-recurrent? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps it was a typo and the transition probabilities were intended to be $P_{i,i+1} = 1-2^{-i}$.

Comment: Maybe, although I don't see a straightforward way to compute the infinite product in this case and the example is supposedly "quite easy". Unless, of course, this is some result considered well known by the authors  that I'm not aware.

Comment: Indeed if we used $P_{i,i+1} = 1-\frac{1}{(i+1)^2}$ it would  be easier to analytically compute $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-\frac{1}{(i+1)^2}) = 1/2$$ Nevertheless $2^{-i}$ converges to 0 much faster than $\frac{1}{(i+1)^2}$ and it is known that $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-2^{-i})>0$. Wolfram gives this value to be approximately $0.288788$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prod+%281-1%2F2%5Ei%29%2C+i%3D1..infty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer gives details on my comment:

The example in the paper should be modified to assuming
$$ P_{i,i+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{(i+1)^2} \quad \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
This is because
$$ \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{(i+1)^2}\right)= 1/2$$
and so if we start in state 1, with probability $1/2$ will will always transition one step forward (in the augmented states) and so we will never visit states in $X_1$.

---

It is also true that
$$ \prod_{j=1}^{\infty}   (1-2^{-j}) >0$$
and so this is why I think that example simply had a typo (they meant $1-2^{-i}$ rather than $2^{-i}$). Indeed it seems difficult to calculate $\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}(1-2^{-j})$ exactly, but we can show it is positive by defining
$$ y_n = \prod_{j=1}^{n} (1-2^{-j}) \quad \forall n \in \{2, 3, 4, ...\}$$
Then for all $n \in \{2, 3, 4, ...\}$ we get
\begin{align}
\log(y_n) &= \sum_{j=1}^n \log(1-2^{-j}) \\
&=\log(1-2^{-1}) + \sum_{j=2}^n\log(1-2^{-j})\\
&=\log(1/2) - \sum_{j=2}^n \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{2^j-1}\right)\\
&\overset{(a)}{\geq} \log(1/2) - \sum_{j=2}^n \frac{1}{2^j-1}\\
&\overset{(b)}{\geq} \log(1/2) - \sum_{j=2}^n \frac{1}{2^{j}-(1/2)2^{j}} \\
&\geq \log(1/2) - \sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{j}-(1/2)2^{j}}\\
&= \log\left(\frac{1}{2e}\right) 
\end{align}
where (a) uses $\log(1+x)\leq x$ for all $x>-1$; (b) uses $\frac{1}{2^j-1}\leq \frac{1}{2^{j}-(1/2)2^{j}}$ for $j \geq 2$. Thus
$$ y_n \geq  \frac{1}{2e} \approx 0.1839 \quad \forall n \in \{2, 3, 4, ...\} $$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification